# CDP version 97 support in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 97, so returning the closest version found: 96

Which version of Selenia supports CDP 97?

Comment: Hi, Please read [mcve] and [tour] then edit your post accordingly. It will help people to understand your problem better and you will receive proper answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, CDP 96 is the latest supported by selenium CDP version.

I saw this commit 23 days ago (Jan 5, 2022).

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/ba01ccd11a9cb75149acaa174a329a91e706ef99

So it should be available in the next released version.